# How to enter TextPrompt field for TComboEdit in Delphi Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10.1 for developing android application and how to enter TextPrompt value for TcomboEdit component?

Comment: Isn't there a `TextPrompt` property in the Object Inspector? If not, it's not supported in `TComboEdit`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Text Prompt field.